# com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryParseException:Unresolved prefixed name

Tags: sparql, jena, ontology

Firstly, I found this relevant question and answer:

- [Unresolved prefixed name: rdfs:subClassOf in SPARQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9782441/we-encountered-an-error-while-trying-to-execute-sparql-query-in-eclipse-can-anyo)

If I add the PREFIX in the SPARQL query it works. However, I don't want to duplicate all the prefixes in all my SPARQL queries, but to define them only once. I tried to do it programmatically for `rdfs:`:

```java
model.setNsPrefix("rdfs", "http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#");
query.setPrefix("rdfs", "http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#");
```

and it works, but if I try to do it with my own ontologies it doesn't work:

```java
model.setNsPrefix("myOnt", "http://example.com/ontologies/myOnt#");
query.setPrefix("myOnt", "http://example.com/ontologies/myOnt#");
```

Comment: Try printing out the query to see why there is an error.

Comment: Did you end up getting this resolved?

Comment: Sorry, I did not receive any notifications concerning these answers. I kept the PREFIX in the SPARQL queries, but I do not like this solution since we have to rewrite them each time, I wanted to find a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can set up a [Prologue](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/arq/org/apache/jena/sparql/core/Prologue.html) to contain you prefix mappings and then pass that into the [QueryFactory](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/arq/org/apache/jena/query/QueryFactory.html) with your specific SPARQL query.

Something like the following worked for me using **Apache Jena 3.0.0**:

```
Prologue queryPrologue = new Prologue();
queryPrologue.setPrefix("skos", "http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#");

String sparql = "SELECT (COUNT ?s) WHERE { ?s a skos:Concept . }"
Query query = QueryFactory.parse(new Query(queryPrologue), sparql, null, null);

try(QueryExecution queryExec = QueryExecutionFactory.create(query, dataset)) {
    // ...
}
```