# Jena- how to retrieve a statement against integer (xsd:int) value- Sparql

Tags: java, rdf, sparql, jena, owl

My owl file is

```
 ....
<filePeakHour rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#int"
>16</filePeakHour>
...
```

I want to create query that retireve SUBJECT where FilePeakHour is 16.

For this, When I run below query in Protege SparqlPlugin, it runs ok

```
SELECT ?x
WHERE { ?x <http://www.semanticweb.org/administrator/ontologies/2014/2/untitled-ontology-5#filePeakHour>"16"^^xsd:int }
```

But when I convert it to Jena format

```
    String queryString = 
    "SELECT ?x WHERE { ?x <http://www.semanticweb.org/administrator/ontologies/2014/2/untitled-ontology-5#filePeakHour>\"16\"^^xsd:int }";
```

it return errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryParseException: Line 1, column 121: Unresolved prefixed name: xsd:int
at com.hp.hpl.jena.sparql.lang.ParserBase.throwParseException(ParserBase.java:661)
at com.hp.hpl.jena.sparql.lang.ParserBase.resolvePName(ParserBase.java:274)
at com.hp.hpl.jena.sparql.lang.sparql_11.SPARQLParser11.PrefixedName(SPARQLParser11.java:4888)
at com.hp.hpl.jena.sparql.lang.sparql_11.SPARQLParser11.iri(SPARQLParser11.java:4872)
at com.hp.hpl.jena.sparql.lang.sparql_11.SPARQLParser11.RDFLiteral(SPARQLParser11.java:4704)
```

How to retrieve xsd:int value from owl file in Jena

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unresolved prefixed name: rdfs:subClassOf in SPARQL query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9782441/unresolved-prefixed-name-rdfssubclassof-in-sparql-query)

Comment: It says right in the exception message "Unresolved prefixed name: xsd:int".  You need to define the prefix for xsd: with `prefix xsd:     <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>` at the beginning of your query.  The linked duplicate was easy to find by searching for the error message "unresolved prefix name". -1 for lack of research effort.

Comment: Also, there's no need to put tag names ([tag:jena] and [tag:sparql]) in the question title;  that's what the tags are for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading the message of the exception, it seems like you should define the prefix in the query:

```
PREFIX xsd:   <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
SELECT ?x
WHERE { ?x <http://www.semanticweb.org/administrator/ontologies/2014/2/untitled-ontology-5#filePeakHour> "16"^^xsd:int }
```

Other common namespaces you'll probably use and their IRIS can be found in [1.2.1 Namespaces](http://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-sparql-query/#docNamespaces) from [SPARQL Query Language for RDF](http://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-sparql-query/#docNamespaces).  The [query validator at sparql.org](http://sparql.org/query-validator.html) also includes a bunch.  There's a searchable listing of common prefixes for RDF at [prefix.cc](http://prefix.cc/), too.